WPML Translation Issue with Ajax Search Pro Placeholder in WordPress
Hello Stack Overflow community,
We're using WordPress with Ajax Search Pro and facing an issue translating strings like 'How can we help you?' with WPML. We have the Pro version, but our support has expired.
Could anyone advise on integrating translation support for these placeholders without the plugin's support?
We have checked and researched this issue but its didn’t work. We also tried creating a new search code but still its not working. we have a pro version for the ajax pro plugin but no support.

Are the strings translation ready at all ? 100% the plugin comes with pot file which you can use to generate your po mo files. Or just pay for the support.
